# Badges do not show in Chrome.

Tags: bug, status-declined, css

I am using Chrome 7.0.5 dev, and the badges do not display on the main site. They do, however, display here.

I think this is a bug, something wrong with the sprites and css.

Answer (score 2):

[We do not support beta (unreleased) browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported).

Also, badges are shown fine in Chrome 6. If you can't fix it by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Refresh, it's more likely a regression bug of Chrome, not us.